# Get value from URL Angular 6

Tags: angular, parameters, angular6

I have below url like
router like

```
{ path: 'login/:token', component: AuthComponent },
```

http://localhost:4200/#/login/id_token=gkdlgk

how I can value of **id_token**?

Comment: Are you trying to use URL route parameters or query params? The structure of the sample URL seems to be mixing route and query params. Did you mean something like */login?id_token=gkdlgk*? Or did you mean */login/gkdlgk*?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I know both url ways. But I have something different url.

Comment: the answers below aren’t working because you are mixing route params and query params. Your url is effectively invalid by normal standards. You should really change it to */login?id_token=whatever* then you can easily use query param map utilities built into the angular router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

public token = "";
ngOnInit() {
  this.token = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("token")
}
```

for more information read this [article](https://medium.com/@christo8989/angular-6-url-parameters-860db789db85)

Answer (score 1):

use `snapshot.paramMap` to get the params

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit(){ 
    let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('token'); 
}
```

Comment: check my url carefully.

Comment: check ur path carefully first. u set the param as `token` in the path

Comment: yes for this I am getting only id_token. but I am not getting its value